# selecting from sys.dm_db_missing_index_details will start to return rows, and then sits and spins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to run some analysis on missing indexes on a server (I haven't ever done it on this server before).  I was running sp_blitzindex and it would hang up on "Inserting data into #MissingIndexes."  I dug into the query and found where it hits sys.dm_db_missing_index_details.

Trying to select from sys.dm_db_missing_index_details will return about 300 records, and then it'll sit and spin.  I didn't want to let it keep going to see how long it would take to finish, but I let it run for over two minutes and it didn't complete.

Why would this take a long time to return?  What would cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like other sessions are blocking the dynamic management view.

`CREATE TABLE` and `DROP TABLE` [force an update to the internal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-missing-index-details-transact-sql#transaction-consistency) maintained for the `sys.dm_db_missing_index_details`.

I was able to recreate a blocking scenario where an open transaction prevents reads against `sys.dm_db_missing_index_details`.  Run this in an SSMS window on your development machine:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.mid_test_2', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.mid_test_2;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.mid_test', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.mid_test;
CREATE TABLE dbo.mid_test
(
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , SomeVal varbinary(2000) NOT NULL DEFAULT (CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2000))
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.mid_test_2
(
    ID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.mid_test(ID)
    , SomeVal varbinary(2000) NOT NULL DEFAULT (CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2000))
);
GO

;WITH src AS 
(
    SELECT v.num
    FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))v(num)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.mid_test (ID)
SELECT s1.num 
    + (s2.num * 10) 
    + (s3.num * 100) 
    + (s4.num * 1000) 
    + (s5.num * 10000) 
FROM src s1
    CROSS JOIN src s2
    CROSS JOIN src s3
    CROSS JOIN src s4
    CROSS JOIN src s5
ORDER BY 1;

;WITH src AS 
(
    SELECT v.num
    FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))v(num)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.mid_test_2 (ID)
SELECT s1.num 
    + (s2.num * 10) 
    + (s3.num * 100) 
    + (s4.num * 1000) 
    + (s5.num * 10000) 
FROM src s1
    CROSS JOIN src s2
    CROSS JOIN src s3
    CROSS JOIN src s4
    CROSS JOIN src s5
ORDER BY 1;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.mid_test m1
    INNER JOIN dbo.mid_test_2 m2 ON m1.ID = m2.ID
WHERE m2.ID = 66666
```

Now, in another SSMS window, run the following (you may need to run it several times depending on how quick you are!)

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_details;
```

For me, the above query blocks until I either commit or rollback the transaction started in the first query window, with:

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

or

```
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Unfortunately, running `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` prior to querying `sys.dm_db_missing_index_details` does not help; it still blocks until the open transaction commits or rolls back.